# adjusting contrast in iOS photo

Tags: ios, ios6, photo

Our iOS 6 app (which is usually run by business users on an iPod Touch 4th Generation, although it is sometimes run on other iOS devices) has a picture-taking feature implemented via `UIImagePickerController`.

Sometimes pictures taken with the app in some lighting conditions are too high-contrast and detail is washed out in bright parts of the picture. Pictures are rarely too low-contrast to be readable. So we're like to "dial down" the contrast of all photos taken in the app.

Obviously we can apply image filtering after-the-fact to adjust contrast, but if the image is so washed out that insufficient detail is present, adjusting later won't help us.

Is there a way to programmatically control brightness and contrast while a photo is being taken in iOS 6?

Comment: If you're open to live filtering of the photos in your preview and capture, I have something that might help with that: https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage (in particular the GPUImageExposureFilter, GPUImageContrastFilter, and GPUImageBrightnessFilter filters, although others may be useful). However, it sounds like you might need to adjust the exposure of the camera itself as it's capturing.

Answer (score 0):

you can add `showsCameraControls` method to display camera controls which would include adjustment for controlling brightness/contrast etc. Let user decide what he needs.

From [Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html) of apple

showsCameraControls
Indicates whether the image picker displays the default camera controls.

@property (nonatomic) BOOL showsCameraControls
Discussion
The default value of this property is YES, which specifies that the default camera controls are visible in the picker. Set it to NO to hide the default controls if you want to instead provide a custom overlay view using the cameraOverlayView property.

Note: In iOS 3.1.3 and earlier, hiding the default camera controls limits you to taking still pictures only, regardless of whether movie capture is available on the device.
If you set this property to NO and provide your own custom controls, you can take multiple pictures before dismissing the image picker interface. However, if you set this property to YES, your delegate must dismiss the image picker interface after the user takes one picture or cancels the operation.

You can access this property only when the source type of the image picker is set to UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera. Attempting to access this property for other source types results in the throwing of an NSInvalidArgumentException exception. Depending on the value you assign to the mediaTypes property, the default controls display the still camera or movie camera interface, or a selection control that lets the user choose the picker interface.